# Проблемы с библиотекой Android Audio Visualizer

Tags: java, android, аудио

Когда я передаю сессию CircleLineVisualizer, то вылетает ошибка:

```
    E/Visualizer-JAVA: Error code -3 when initializing Visualizer.
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: music.player.musicplayer.audio.media.fm.video.radio.video.songs.equalizer.apps.free.android.lalala.download.search, PID: 16894
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{music.player.musicplayer.audio.media.fm.video.radio.video.songs.equalizer.apps.free.android.lalala.download.search/musicplayer.audioplayer.equalizer.mp3player.activity.PlayerActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot initialize Visualizer engine, error: -3
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2977)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3114)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:113)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:71)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1859)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6831)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:927)
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot initialize Visualizer engine, error: -3
        at android.media.audiofx.Visualizer.<init>(Visualizer.java:218)
        at com.gauravk.audiovisualizer.base.BaseVisualizer.setAudioSessionId(BaseVisualizer.java:196)
        at musicplayer.audioplayer.equalizer.mp3player.activity.PlayerActivity.onCreate(PlayerActivity.java:135)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7224)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7213)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
```

Вот, как я это делаю:

```
int audioSessionId = mMediaPlayer.getAudioSessionId();
    if (audioSessionId != -1)
        mVisualizer.setAudioSessionId(audioSessionId);
```

И вот xml файл:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_player"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".activity.PlayerActivity">

<com.gauravk.audiovisualizer.visualizer.CircleLineVisualizer
                xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/blast"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                custom:avDensity="0.8"
                custom:avType="fill"
                custom:avColor="@color/av_dark_blue"
                custom:avSpeed="normal"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Итак, что перым делом делает разработчик, когда сталкивается с проблемой при использовании сторонних библиотек?

Правильно, идет на страницу библиотеки, переходит в раздел `Issues` и ищет ответ на свой вопрос. И только если он его там не находит, он идет на `SO` и задает его там.

Но ладно, я сделал это за тебя)

Вот [ответ](https://github.com/gauravk95/audio-visualizer-android/issues/8) на твой вопрос